# MySQL syntax error #1064 INSERT INTO

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INSERT INTO 'tblproduct' (`id`, `name`, `code`, `image`,
>   `price`) VALUES(1, '3' at line 11

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblproduct` (
`id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`image` text NOT NULL,
`price` double(10,2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `product_code` (`code`)
 )

 INSERT INTO 'tblproduct' (`id`, `name`, `code`, `image`, `price`) VALUES
 (1, '3D Camera', '3DcAM01', 'product-images/camera.jpg', 1500.00),
 (2, 'External Hard Drive', 'USB02', 'product-images/external-hard-drive.jpg', 800.00),
 (3, 'Wrist Watch', 'wristWear03', 'product-images/watch.jpg', 300.00);
```

Comment: Use backtick ` instead of single quotes with table name `'tblproduct'`

Comment: `'tblproduct'` to ``tblproduct`` or with backtick `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two problems in this a `;` is missing after  `CREATE TABLE` and also use backticks for `tblproduct`

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tblproduct` (
`id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`code` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
`image` text NOT NULL,
`price` double(10,2) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
 UNIQUE KEY `product_code` (`code`)
 ); 

 INSERT INTO `tblproduct` (`id`, `name`, `code`, `image`, `price`) VALUES
 (1, '3D Camera', '3DcAM01', 'product-images/camera.jpg', 1500.00),
 (2, 'External Hard Drive', 'USB02', 'product-images/external-hard-drive.jpg', 800.00),
 (3, 'Wrist Watch', 'wristWear03', 'product-images/watch.jpg', 300.00);
```

Comment: hey thanks bro it's works.. thank you

Comment: Welcome buddy, consider accepting answer.